# Create a Modal to Add new fields dynamically

Tags: webforms

I have to develop a contest page. Every participant may have one or more codes that can use to participate in the event. After that the user must fill a form with their personal data so they can be contacted  in case they win the contest.

How could I add a `[+]` button that opens a modal window asking me how many code field would I need? If I write 5 for example, we create dynamically 5 code fields to the input.

I managed to create an add more button that add just one more button, but for clients requirements, we need to use a popup that ask how many fields we need.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Are you sure you are using webform module to create the fields?

Comment: Yup, I can add the fields when using the webform module. My problem is when the visitors enter the webform.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how this can be done entirely with Webforms. One option is to include in this webform all necessary fields, including the ones that would appear as a modal dialog. Even better, group these as a fieldset.

Then in a custom module or theme include some jQuery logic with which would be very easy to create a modal dialog in the same page. There is a [dialog widget in jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) and this is a [relevant question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905819/jquery-modal-confirmation-dialog-not-submitting-form).